# Apps Script - Deploy from manifest - Install add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, version-control, google-apps-script-add-on

The Apps Script code editor has a feature to "Deploy from manifest."

After creating and saving a new deployment version, a link is shown that states:

> Install add-on

[image: Apps Script deployment - install add-on]

I can not find any documentation for what that does.
I already know about documentation at:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/deployments
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments

I've clicked the link to "Install add-on", and I get a message stating:

Deployment installed

[image: Deployment installed]

But I do not know what happened, or what the consequences are.

It obviously doesn't publish the script as an add-on, because that needs to be done through Google Cloud and the GSuite Marketplace SDK.  And in the example shown here, I don't even have a GCP project associated with the Apps Script project.

I don't know if I need to click "Install add-on" in order to use that version in the add-on publishing, or whether it's not needed.

- What does it actually do?
- Is it necessary?
- Is there some benefit to it?
- Is there any documentation explaining what "Install add-on" does?

Answer (score 1):

I use this option to install my Gmail add-on on the Google accounts I use while on development, prior to publishing.

Check-out this link https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on

I don't know how it works for editor add-ons, but for my Gmail/Gsuite add-on, it's pretty straightforward. I can use this option to install on any G Suite account from the same domain, and any Gmail account, provided I share the project with the account first.

Comment: It seems that the "Install add-on" and "Uninstall add-on" link relates directly to the "host application."  The "Install" and "Uninstall" add-on links, control whether the add-on is available in the "host application." But I'm not sure what the "host application" is or how the add-on is made available in the host application to begin with?  Users can install the add-on through the host application **OR** the G Suite Marketplace.  But I don't think that the G Suite Marketplace is also considered a host application?  Or is it?

Comment: Okay, "host applications" are GMail, Google Calendar and Google Drive.  So, if my add-on is a Google Forms add-on, then I don't have a host application.  I guess.  And therefore installing it to a host application for an editor add-on probably does nothing.  I notice in the documentation that there is a GMail icon next to the "Install add-on" link, showing what the "host application" is.  But in my deployments, there is no app icon, which probably indicates that I have no host application.